# Is there any way to interpret GLPK or lp files through Anaconda or Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, gnu, glpk

I am a novice to both Python and Linear Programming. I currently have Python 3 on my device through Anaconda, and I have downloaded all the installation files for [GLPK](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glpk/) and [PyGLPK](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~jpp/code/python-glpk/). I have also installed the [glpk condo package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/glpk) multiple times. Despite all of this, I find myself unable to interpret GLPK .lp files on any Python API, such as the jupyter or sublime text; i.e. I cannot **import glpk**. Previous answers have recommended using PyGLPK in order to get around this, but it only functions on [Python 2](http://www.tfinley.net/software/pyglpk/discussion.html). PuPL was also recommended as a tool that is able to interpret .lp files, but I haven't been able to make that work (PuLP works fine on both my command prompt and anaconda, but it cannot interpret .lp files, only create them). In essence, I have two fundamental questions.

1. Is the Anaconda GLPK package functional? A few of my peers have also found trouble getting it to work.
2. Are there any tools that allow you to build, and more importantly read .lp files through Python 3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an expert, but it seems possible with https://github.com/biosustain/swiglpk, which is available as conda package.

Comment: I know it's been 5 years but have you found a solution? I'm having problems installing GLPK on Anaconda. It is installed in my computer but Anaconda is not recognising it, it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a long, I finally found [Python-MIP](https://python-mip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) to be a good solution to this.

Other more cumbersome and not well-documented options are using commercial APIs for IBM CPLEX or Gurobi, especially if you are targetting a massive problem. They both have free demo licences for limited problem size.